# Proving an inequality about norms.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Given
$$\|x\|_s=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_j|^s\right)^{\!1/s} \quad \text{for $1\le s < \infty$}$$
and
$$\|x\|_\infty=\max\{|x_j|:1\le s\lt n\},$$
I need to prove that if $1\le s$ and $0\le t$ then
$$\|x\|_\infty \le \|x\|_{s+t} \le \|x\|_s$$
for every vector $x\in \Bbb C^n$.

Firstly, I do not even see why this statement is true:
$$\bigl(|x_1|^s+|x_2|^s\bigr)^{1/s} \ge \bigl(|x_1|^{s+t}+|x_2|^{s+t}\bigr)^{1/(s+t)}\ge \max\bigl(|x_1|,|x_2|\bigr).$$  My idea was to proceed by induction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\def\C{\mathbb C}\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}x\in \C^n$, suppose first that $\norm x_s = 1$. Then $\abs{x_i} \le 1$ for $1 \le i \le n$. We have then for each $i$ that $\abs{x_i}^{t} \le 1$. Hence
\begin{align*}
  \norm x_{s+t}^{s+t} &= \sum_{i=1}^n \abs{x_i}^{s+t}\\
       &= \sum_{i=1}^n \abs{x_i}^s\abs{x_i}^t\\
       &\le \sum_{i=1}^n \abs{x_i}^s\\
       &= \norm x_s^s\\
       &= 1.
\end{align*}
Hence $\norm x_{s+t} \le 1 = \norm x_s$. If now $x \ne 0$ is arbitrary, set $y := x/\norm x_s$, then $\norm y_s = 1$, hence 
$$ \norm{\frac{x}{\norm x_s}}_{s+t} = \norm y_s \le 1 \iff \frac{\norm x_s}{\norm x_{s+t}}\le 1 \iff \norm x_s \le \norm x_{s+t} $$
The inequality for the $\infty$-norm is easy: Let $x\in \C^n$, then there is an $1 \le i \le n$ with $\norm x_\infty = \abs{x_i}$, hence 
$$ \norm x_{\infty} = \bigl(\abs{x_i}^s\bigr)^{1/s} \le \left(\sum_{j=1}^n \abs{x_j}^s\right)^{1/s} = \norm x_s $$